# No Importing db_connect from dbutils

Tags: database, dbutils

I installed py-dbutils (pip install py-dbutils), but when I run gives and error message: from dbutils import db_connect
ImportError: cannot import name 'db_connect' from 'dbutils'
I do not know if **db_connect** changed to another name. Thanks.

```
from dbutils import db_connect
DEFAULT_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'mailroom.db')

def db_connect(db_path = DEFAULT_PATH):
   '''Connect to the database and also creates it'''
   conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
   return conn
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.  I'm not quite understanding your code.  What is your script's name?